# MenuItem click only works when child item is clicked

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I have a larger PowerShell Script that is importing XAML code into it. Here's part of the code:

**XAML**

```
<Menu x:Name="menu" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile" Header="File">
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_History" Header="_History"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_Recent" Header="_Recent">
            <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_Recent1"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_Recent2"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_Recent3"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_Recent4"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_Recent5"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_ShowMore" Header="_Show More"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_FlushDNS" Header="_Flush DNS"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_KillProcess" Header="Kill Process"/>
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuFile_Close" Header="_Close"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="menuEdit" Header="Edit">
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuEdit_ConvertIP" Header="Convert IP" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="menuHelp" Header="Help">
        <MenuItem x:Name="menuHelp_About" Header="About"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

**PowerShell**

```
$menuFile.Add_Click({
    $txtInput.Text = "It worked!"    
})
```

The problem is that the above PowerShell code is only ran when one of the child items is clicked, not when $menuFile is clicked. I have looked and looked and I cannot figure out why this is happening and how to fix it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want `$txtInput.Text = "It worked!"` to happen as soon as the menu is initiated, but the current behavior is that it happens when one of the menu options is selected, right?

Comment: Correct. I am using the $txtinput just as a test to confirm it works. What I would like to happen is update $txtInput when I click on the File menu item. What actually happens is nothing happens when I click on the File menu item, but when I click on one of the child items (such as History or Close) then it updates $txtinput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a different event handler than Click. You want GotFocus or something like that.Try this instead

```
$menuFile.Add_GotFocus({$txtInput.Text = "It worked!"})
```

You can check out all of the events you can add event handlers to by piping to `Get-Member` as such:

```
$menuFile | Get-Member -MemberType Methods -force |?{$_.Name -like 'add*'}
```

Then just look for the methodsJust for kicks I tried this, and it worked as expected:

```
$menuFile.Add_GotFocus({$menuFile.FontSize = 16})
$menuFile.Add_LostFocus({$menuFile.FontSize = 12})
```

Then when I clicked on the File menu the font size for it and its children got larger, but when I moved to a different menu or clicked away the font size shrank back to font size 12.